# Восстановление пароля (новая версия) оцените

Tags: php, инспекция-кода, пароль

```
<?php

//Если юзверь нажал кнопку отправки
if (isset ($_POST['ok']))
{
//Коннектимся к матрице
mysql_connect ("localhost", "root") or die ("Error connect to server");
mysql_select_db("aaa") or die ("Error select db");

//Инициализация
$email = !empty ($_POST['email']) ? trim($_POST['email']) : NULL;

//Смотрим, че там намутил юзверь
if ($email != '')
{
    $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT `email` FROM `users`
                            WHERE `email` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."'");
    if (mysql_num_rows ($sql)  > 0)

    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($sql);

        //Генерим новый пароль
        $new_pass = substr(md5((time()*mktime()*rand())), 0, 10);

        //Заносим новый пароль в базу
        $sql2 = mysql_query ("UPDATE `users` SET `pass` = '".md5($new_pass)."'
                                WHERE `email` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."'");

        if ($sql !== FALSE)
        {

            //Отправляем новый пароль
            $to = $row["email"];
            $from = "admin@mail.ru";
            $charset = "utf-8";
            $tema = "=?".$charset."?".base64_encode("Восстановление пароля")."?=";
            $header = "Content-type:text/html; charset=\"".$charset."\"\r\n";
            $header .= "From: <admin@mail.ru>\r\n";
            $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $header .= "Date: ".date("D d M Y h:i:s O")."\r\n";
            $msg = "Ваш новый пароль: ".$new_pass;
            $mail = mail ($to, $from, $msg, $header);
            if ($mail !== FALSE)
                echo '<p>Пароль отправлен вам на почту</p>';
            else
                echo '<p>Ошибка отправки</p>';
        }
        else
            echo mysql_error();

        }
    else
        echo '<p>Нету юзверя с таким email</p>';
}
else
    echo '<p>Вы не ввели Ваше мыло</p>';

}
else
echo '<p>Введите Ваш email, на него будет отправлен новый пароль</p>';

?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" /><br/>
<input type="submit" name="ok" value="Восстановить" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то не очень логично - пришел первый попавший, кто знает мой e-mail, заказал восстановление пароля и у меня сменился пароль... Поставил:

```
curl -d 'email=мой@e-mail&ok=1' http://url.где.этотскрипт
```

на исполнение скажем раз в 10 мин и порядок, большая гадость мне обеспечена.

По-существу: Коннект к базе данных перенести после проверки на пустой e-mail

**UPDATE**:

curl - это command-line утилита с помошью которой можно выполнять уйму действий как то скачать/загрузить/выполнить форму и еще много полезных или вредных действий.

Ну а защита - формируем еще одну таблицу где хранятся запросы на восстановление вид у нее:

```
id, timestamp, login
```

При запросе записываем (обновляем) запись в этой таблице, в качестве id пишем какой-нибудь md5, timestamp = now(), логин и e-mail соответственно, отсылаем на e-mail письмо со ссылкой на страницу восстановления содержащий id.

Эта страница при выполнении проверяет наличие id в таблице и если есть - меняет пароль или спрашивает пользователя какой пароль нужно поставить и удаляет эту запись из таблицы восстановления паролей.

Примерно так

Comment: шо делать в таком случае? где править?

Comment: как защищиться?

Comment: и что такое? 
    curl -d 'email=мой@e-mail&ok=1' http://url.где.этотскрипт

Comment: Обновил ответ, так как в комментарий не лезет

Comment: а в одной таблице лучше не делать, да?

Comment: Не имеет особого смысла, по запросам к БД - одинаково выходит, а с отдельной таблицей гибкость выше, ну там timestamp раз в день проверять на предмет того что-бы запросы на восстановления паролей долго не висели